# Binding an ItemsControl to a derived type with XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, frameworks, entity

Is it possible to bind an ItemsControl to a derived type (from an abstract base) using XAML only?

I have a Class called "RouteStop".  Within "RouteStop", there is a collection of a class "Payment".

Payment is an abstract class with derived classes ExpectedPayment and ActualPayment.

I have an ItemsControl bound to "RouteStops".  For each row, there are zero-to-many "ExpectedPayment" and zero-to-many "ActualPayment" records.  I want to display the two derived classes in side-by-side ItemsControls for each RouteStop.

I understand you can use Linq to retrieve the derived type.  As in...

```
context.Payments.OfType<ExpectedPayment>()
```

But I'd prefer not to set this using code on a row by row basis.  Is there a way to do this declaratively with XAML? Do I have to modify the SSDL to create a way to access the derived types?

And if this is not possible, what would be a best practice?

Thank you in advance for any time spent on this.

Comment: I reevaluated my design, and instead of the collection of Payments (the base class) in my RouteStop object, I modified the edmx to have two separate Collections, one of each derived type (ActualPayments and ExpectedPayments).

Now I can reference them directly...  However!  I'd still like to know if my original post question is possible.